# Counting number of different elements in a list in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list of natural numbers and returns as output the amount of different elements in it. For example, if I have the list [1,2,2,4,1], my function DifElem should output "3". I've tried many things, the closest I've gotten is this:

```
Fixpoint DifElem (l : list nat) : nat :=
   match l with
   | [] => 0
   | m::tm => 
   let n := listWidth tm in
   if (~ In m tm) then S n else n
end.
```

My logic is this: if m is not in the tail of the list then add one to the counter. If it is, do not add to the counter, so I'll only be counting once: when it's the last time it appears. I get the error:

```
Error: The term "~ In m tm" has type "Prop"
which is not a (co-)inductive type.
```

In is part of Coq's list standard library `Coq.Lists.List.` It is defined there as:

```
Fixpoint In (a:A) (l:list A) : Prop :=
   match l with
   | [] => False
   | b :: m => b = a \/ In a m
end.
```

I think I don't understand well enough how to use If then statements in definitions, Coq's documentation was not helpful enough.

I also tried this definition with `nodup` from the same library:

```
Definition Width (A : list nat ) := length (nodup ( A ) ).
```

In this case what I get as error is:

```
The term "A" has type "list nat" while it is expected to have
type "forall x y : ?A0, {x = y} + {x <> y}".
```

And I'm quiet confused as to what's going on here. I'd appreciate your help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be confusing propositions (`Prop`) and booleans (`bool`). I'll try to explain in simple terms: a *proposition* is something you prove (according to Martin-Lof's interpretation it is a set of proofs), and a *boolean* is a datatype which can hold only 2 values (`true` / `false`). Booleans can be useful in computations, when there are only two possible outcomes and no addition information is not needed. You can find more on this topic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14201706/2747511) by @Ptival or a thorough section on this in the Software Foundations book by B.C. Pierce et al. (see [Propositions and Booleans](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/Logic.html#lab186) section).

Actually, `nodup` is the way to go here, but Coq wants you to provide a way of deciding on equality of the elements of the input list. If you take a look at the definition of [`nodup`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html):

```
Hypothesis decA: forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y}.

Fixpoint nodup (l : list A) : list A :=
  match l with
    | [] => []
    | x::xs => if in_dec decA x xs then nodup xs else x::(nodup xs)
  end.
```

you'll notice a hypothesis `decA`, which becomes an additional argument to the `nodup` function, so you need to pass `eq_nat_dec` (decidable equality fot `nats`), for example, like this: `nodup eq_nat_dec l`.

So, here is a possible solution:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition count_uniques (l : list nat) : nat :=
  length (nodup eq_nat_dec l).

Eval compute in count_uniques [1; 2; 2; 4; 1].
(* = 3 : nat *)
```

*Note*: The `nodup` function works since Coq v8.5.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually confused about what Coq could take in "If... then..." statements. It can take booleans. Can it take ANY inductive definition with only 2 constructors? Or what are the constraints? Thank you very much for your suggestion. Both the source and how to fix my code were very helpful!

Comment: Yes, the `if` statement treats any two-constructor types as boolean. The first constructor is treated as true. More on this you can find in Adam Chlipala's [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) book ([here](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html)).

Comment: FYI, the `MoreLogic` chapter of SF has been removed from more recent versions of SF :( I'm not sure where to find a mirror that does not include the solutions.

Comment: @CarlPatenaudePoulin Thanks! I replaced the broken link with a [new one](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/Logic.html#lab186) which IIRC explains the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Anton's solution using the standard library I'd like to remark that mathcomp provides specially good support for this use case along with a quite complete theory on `count` and `uniq`. Your function becomes:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype ssrnat seq.

Definition count_uniques (T : eqType) (s : seq T) := size (undup s).
```

In fact, I think the count_uniques name is redundant, I'd prefer to directly use `size (undup s)` where needed.

Answer (score 5):

Using sets:

```
Require Import MSets.
Require List. Import ListNotations.

Module NatSet := Make Nat_as_OT.

Definition no_dup l := List.fold_left (fun s x => NatSet.add x s) l NatSet.empty.
Definition count_uniques l := NatSet.cardinal (no_dup l).

Eval compute in count_uniques [1; 2; 2; 4; 1].
```